# Launching separate visual windows in Powershell (start "%%A powershell.exe in CMD)

Tags: shell, powershell, for-loop, cmd, command

Currently I have to cmd /c a separate CMD file which I would like to eliminate

I tried

```
cmd /c "for /f %%A in (foo.txt)do start "%%A" powershell.exe "get-eventlog -logname security -instanceID 4625 -after $timeCut -message "*bar*" -comp %%A | select machinename,timegenerated, eventid, @{n='AccountName';e={$_.ReplacementStrings[5]}}""
```

but I think there are too many " and I did both %A and %%A

I would like to launch a separate window for each server in just PS.

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. Why do you think you need separate windows?

Comment: So I can quickly visually scan 100+ servers without opening any log files or queries.  I already have a working solution I am just trying to consolidate it to one PS file with a possible cmd /c "for /f" call or pure PS.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "visually scanning", but opening 100+ terminals is just insane. If you want to retrieve log excerpts from those servers: use [jobs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/12/31/using-windows-powershell-jobs.aspx). Better yet, set up a loghost and have relevant events [forwarded](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748890.aspx) to that host.

Comment: Actually it works quite well, you tile them vertically, they close automatically, if there is a legit 4625 error there will be many entries and they will be the only ones left open.  Any thoughts why my cmd /c "for /f" is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out and was able to keep it to a single line

```
(get-content foo.txt) | foreach-object {start  powershell "-noexit get-eventlog -logname security -instanceID 4625 -after $timeCut -message *bar* -comp $_ | select machinename,timegenerated, eventid, @{n='AccountName';e={$_.ReplacementStrings[5]}}"}
```